# Duplicacion de objetos en Java

Tags: java, poo

Alguien me podría hacer un ejemplo de como puedo duplicar una objeto.
Tengo esto pero no me funciona.

```
interface Cloneable {
}

class Punto implements Cloneable{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Punto(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Punto() {
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }
    public Object clone(){
        Object obj=null;
        try{
            obj=super.clone();
        }catch(CloneNotSupportedException ex){
            System.out.println(" no se puede duplicar");
        }
        return obj;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String texto="origen: ("+x+", "+y+")";
        return texto;
    }
}

class EjemploDeUso {
   public static void main(String[]args){
    Punto punto1 = new Punto(3,4);
    Punto copia = (Punto)punto1.clone();

    System.out.println(punto1.toString());
    System.out.println(copia.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido a SOes.

Para hacer una clase ***"clonable"*** estás apuntando mas o menos bien. En la clase tienes añadir el `implements Clonable` (para especificar que esa clase tendrá ese comportamiento), luego sobreescribir el método `clone()` y hacerlo público, y llamar a `super.clone()` en su interior.

***¿Y qué hice mal?***
No deberías escribir sobre la interfaz Cloneable, ya que es una interfaz Java por defecto.
Cuando un método arroja algún tipo de excepción, en Java debes especificarlo mediante la palabra reservada **throws** `<tipoExcepción>`. Acomodando tu ejemplo, puedes probar que funciona:

```
class Punto implements Cloneable {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Punto(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Punto() {
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }

    public Punto clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
         Punto clonmalefico = (Punto) super.clone();
         return clonmalefico;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String texto="origen: ("+x+", "+y+")";
        return texto;
    }
}

class EjemploDeUso {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Punto punto1 = new Punto(3,4);
        Punto copia=null;
        try {
            copia = punto1.clone();
        } catch(CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
            System.out.println("No se puede clonar");
        }

        System.out.println(punto1.toString());
        System.out.println(copia.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Primero que nada, tener cuidado al utilizar la interfaz `Cloneable`, puesto que se considera técnicamente rota y que provee más problemas que beneficios, tal como lo explica [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch), uno de los diseñadores del lenguaje Java, en su libro Effective Java. Aquí una {publicación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) donde explica esto en más detalle (enlace en inglés). Lo más resaltante de la publicación (énfasis mía):

> There are a few design flaws, the biggest of which is that the **`Cloneable` interface does not have a `clone` method**. And that means it simply doesn't work: making something `Cloneable` doesn't say anything about what you can do with it. Instead, it says something about what it can do internally.
>
> (...)
>
> `Object`'s `clone` method is very tricky. It's based on field copies, and it's "extra-linguistic." **It creates an object without calling a constructor.** There are no guarantees that it preserves the invariants established by the constructors. (...)  The clone generally shares state with the object being cloned. If that state is mutable, you don't have two independent objects. **If you modify one, the other changes as well**.
>
> (...)
>
> It's a shame that `Cloneable` is broken, but it happens. The original Java APIs were done very quickly under a tight deadline to meet a closing market window. (...) **`Cloneable` is a weak spot, and I think people should be aware of its limitations.**

Traducidos a español (énfasis mía):

> Hay algunos problemas de diseño, siendo el más grande que **la interfaz `Cloneable` no tiene un método `clone`**. Y eso significa que simplemente no funciona: haciendo algo `Cloneable` no dice nada sobre qué puedes hacer con ello. En su lugar, dice algo sobre lo que puede hacer internamente.
>
> (...)
>
> El método `clone` de la clase `Object` es muy tramposo. Se basa en copiar campos, y es "extra-lingüístico". **Crea un objeto sin llamar a un constructor.** No hay garantía de que preserve los invariantes establecidos por los constructores. (...) El clon generalmente comparte estado con el objeto que es clonado. Si ese estado es mutable, no tienes dos objetos independientes. **Si modificas uno, el otro cambia también.**
>
> (...)
>
> Es una lástima que `Cloneable` esté roto, pero sucede. Las APIs originales de Java fueron hechas muy rápidamente bajo una fecha de plazo muy estrecha para alcanzar un intervalo próximo de mercado. (...) **`Cloneable` es un punto débil, y pienso que las personas deben ser conscientes de sus limitaciones.**

Por ende, el uso de la interfaz [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) debe ser **evitado en su mayoría de veces**.

---

Sobre el problema concreto: ¿cómo clonar un objeto? Partiendo de que tomamos la definición de tu clase `Punto` de esta manera:

```
public class Punto {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Punto(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }
    //no existe método clone()

    //el resto de métodos no son relevantes para este caso
}
```

Existen por lo menos tres formas fuera de `Object#clone` para lograrlo:

1. Crear un constructor de copia. Esto significa que la clase que necesita un clon va a aceptar un objeto del mismo tipo de la clase y se va a encargar de crear el clon. Aquí un ejemplo:

   ```
   public class Punto {
       //código actual de la clase...

       //se agrega este código
       //se creará una instancia como clon de otra instancia
       public Punto(Punto otroPunto) {
           this(otroPunto.x, otroPunto.y);
       }
   }

   //...

   Punto punto = new Punto(5, 8);
   System.out.println(String.format("Punto: (%d, %d)", punto.getX(), punto.getY());
   Punto puntoClon = new Punto(punto);
   System.out.println(String.format("Punto: (%d, %d)", puntoClon.getX(), puntoClon.getY());
   ```

   Puntos a favor:

   - El mejor rendimiento en tiempo de ejecución.
   - Te aseguras de copiar todos los campos. Puedes definir entre tener un clon superficial o clon profundo.
   - Te permite flexibilidad para crear el clone profundo.

   Puntos en contra:

   - Trabajo manual.
   - Cuando la clase tiene muchos atributos, el código del constructor de copia se vuelve largo y complicado, sobretodo cuando existen muchos atributos de tipo clase o interfaz.
   - Debes asegurarte que los atributos de tipo clase también posean alguna manera de ser clonados vía un constructor de copia u otro mecanismo.
2. Utilizar reflexión. Se trabaja con la metadata del objeto: clase, atributos definidos, atributos definidos en los ancestros, etc. Esto permite crear el clon de una manera limpia y tener un método que puede clonar cualquier tipo de objeto.

   ```
   Punto punto = new Punto(5, 8);
   System.out.println(String.format("Punto: (%d, %d)", punto.getX(), punto.getY());
   Punto puntoClon = BeanUtils.cloneBean(punto);
   System.out.println(String.format("Punto: (%d, %d)", puntoClon.getX(), puntoClon.getY());
   ```

   Puedes revisar la [implementación de `BeanUtilsBean#cloneBean`](https://github.com/apache/commons-beanutils/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.java) que es el método que se llama cuando utilizas `BeanUtils.cloneBean` y hace el trabajo real.

   Puntos a favor:

   - Obtienes un clon superficial con relativamente poco esfuerzo.
   - Trabajo automatizado que apoya el reuso. Puedes clonar cualquier cosa con este método.
   - No requiere que cambies el código de tus clases.

   Puntos en contra:

   - Puesto que utiliza reflexión, es más lento que el constructor de copia. (En pruebas que he hecho utilizando JMH, he visto que puede ser hasta 10 veces más lento, pero esto es variable).
   - No obtienes un clon profundo, pero te da las herramientas para hacer un método que lo pueda hacer.
3. Utilizando serialización/deserialización. Lo que se hace es serializar el objeto que será clonado. Al estar serializado, se posee una representación del objeto en un formato diferente. La serialización comúnmente es a bytes utilizando el mecanismo de serialización nativo de Java, pero también puede ser a XML, a JSON, a BSON o a cualquier otro formato que sea conveniente. Al deserializar esta información, se obtiene un nuevo objeto con la misma información del objeto original. Aquí un ejemplo utilizando [`SerializationUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) (clase externa que ya provee una implementación para lograr esto):

   ```
   //se agrega que la clase implemente la interfaz Serializable
   //por restricciones de la librería
   public class Punto implements Serializable {
       //resto del código de la clase
   }

   Punto punto = new Punto(5, 8);
   System.out.println(String.format("Punto: (%d, %d)", punto.getX(), punto.getY());
   Punto puntoClon = SerializationUtils.clone(punto);
   System.out.println(String.format("Punto: (%d, %d)", puntoClon.getX(), puntoClon.getY());
   ```

   Puedes revisar [la implementación de `SerializationUtils#clone`](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.java).

   Puntos a favor:

   - Obtienes un clon profundo sin importar la complejidad de la clase.
   - Trabajo automatizado que apoya el reuso. Puedes clonar cualquier cosa con este método.

   Puntos en contra:

   - La serialización/deserialización puede tener restricciones. Por ejemplo, que las clases a ser clonadas implementen la interfaz `Serializable`.
   - Su tiempo de ejecución es mucho más lento que los otros métodos.
   - Requiere espacio adicional para realizar el clon, ya sea en memoria (RAM) o en disco. Si clonas un objeto muy pesado, puedes tener problemas de memoria.

### ¿Cuál de estos métodos utilizar?

**DEPENDE**. Depende de lo que necesites exactamente. Evalúa los beneficios y dificultades de cada uno sobre tus necesidades y elige lo más apropiado para tu situación. En tu caso, como parece que solo necesitas clonar una sola clase que tiene una estructura simple, convendría utilizar la primera forma: el constructor de copia.

Comment: Upvoted. A veces uno por no tener disponibilidad horaria evita explayarse sobre las ventajas y desventajas de programar de cierto modo. Y adhiero 100% con Luiggi respecto a la interfaz `Cloneable`. Nunca he utilizado reflexión, pero sin dudas te sugiero que leas esta respuesta y la tengas en cuenta, ya que sin dudas deberías considerarla por sobre la mía.

Answer (score 0):

lo mejor seria que crearas un nuevo objeto vacio y que hagas copia de cada atributo contenido dentro de esa clase como por ejemplo.

```
 public class Persona
 {
   private String nombre;
   public Persona()
   {
       super();
   }
   public Persona(String nombre)
   {
      this.nombre = nombre;
   }
   public String getNombre()
   {
      return nombre;
   }
   public void setNombre(String nombre)
   {
      this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

y en la clase main

```
public class Testteo 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Persona persona = new Persona("Jaime");
      Persona persona2 = new Persona();

      persona2.setNombre(persona.getNombre());
  }
}
```

Comment: En este caso, `new Persona();` no compilaría.

Comment: obviamente la clase Testteo le falta el main y dentro de ella lo que corresponde...

Comment: Bueno, hay eso. Pero yo me refería a que ese constructor sin parámetros no existe en la clase `Persona`.

Comment: bueno tienes razón... solo faltaria agregarlo...

Comment: gracias sstan por la corrección..

Answer (score 0):

clonar
Invernadero inv2 = null;

```
    /*
     * Inicio clonaci�n
     */
    //ByteArrayInputStream
    //ByteArrayOutputStream
    //ObjectInputStream
    //ObjectOutputStream
    byte[] Invernadero = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(inv);
        out.flush();
        Invernadero = bos.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Invernadero);
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        inv2 = (Invernadero) in.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        
    }

    
    inv2.setName("Nuevo Invernadero");
    inv2.status();
    inv.status();
```

Comment: Saludos @RaulGonzales, tu respuesta estaría mucho mas completa si explicas el código que propones, como resuelve el problema de OP y si es posible agregar algo de documentación. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```java
ArrayList<T> elementos = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> contador = new ArrayList<>();

   
/**
 * Añadimos el elemento incremetando el contador
 * @param value 
 */
    public void Count(T value) {

        if (!elementos.contains(value)) {

            elementos.add(value);
            contador.add(1);

        }else{
            int index = elementos.indexOf(value);
            contador.set(index, contador.get(index)+1);
        }

    }
/**
 * Eliminamos el elemento decrementando el contador 
 * @param value 
 */
    public void discount(T value) {

        if (elementos.contains(value)) {

            
            int index = elementos.indexOf(value);
            if(contador.get(index)==1){
                elementos.remove(index);
                contador.remove(index);
            }else{
            contador.set(index, contador.get(index)-1);
            }
              
        }
    }

    public void delete(T value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementos.size(); i++) {
            if(elementos.get(i).equals(value)){
                elementos.remove(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < elementos.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(elementos.get(i));
        }
        

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String listar= "[";
        
        for(int i=0;i<elementos.size()-1;i++){
            
                
            listar += elementos.get(i) + ": " + contador.get(i)+ ", ";
            
            
             
            
           
        }
        
        return  listar +  "]";
        
    }

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Contador <Integer> contador1 = new Contador<Integer>();
        
        System.out.println("Metodo count: ");
        
        contador1.Count(1);
        contador1.Count(2);
        contador1.Count(1);
        contador1.Count(3);
        contador1.Count(1);
        contador1.Count(2);
        contador1.Count(1);
        contador1.Count(3);
        System.out.println(contador1.toString());
        
        
        System.out.println("-------------------\n");
        System.out.println("Metodo discount: \n");
        contador1.discount(2);
        contador1.discount(1);
        System.out.println(contador1.toString());
        
        System.out.println("-------------------\n");
        System.out.println("Metodo delete: \n");
        contador1.delete(3);
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor explica como tu respuesta resuelve el problema de OP, las preguntas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, no estaría demás agregar algo de explicación. ;)

Comment: Creo que te falta algo de contextualización, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)